# Is there a faster way to find all files?

Tags: c#

The following code will get all files in the system:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        if (d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
        {
            list.Add(d.Name);
        }
    }
    var listfile = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        GetAllFiles(item, listfile);
    }
    foreach (var item in listfile)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

public void GetAllFiles(string path, IList<string> files)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList()
            .ForEach(f => files.Add(f));

        Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToList()
            .ForEach(f => GetAllFiles(f, files));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

It works but is very slow. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Also getting *every* file on disk across all disks is always going to be slow. There are various backup applications and disk space management applications and none of those are ever fast. Disk is the slowest part of a PC, it has always been. If I were you I would concentrate on figuring out how *not* to have to do this. Perhaps have the user specify a folder or search parameter first before you enumerate everything on all disks.

Comment: Enumerating files using OS-provided APIs is always slow (because of ACL enforcement, etc). Use a third-party service like voidtools’ _Everything_ to instantly search NTFS files by indexing the MFT directly.

Comment: Have you tried using `Directory.GetFiles` using `SearchOption.AllDirectories`? That does the recursion for you.

Comment: @Dai - **Everything** is like black magic :-o

Comment: @ja72 There's no black-magic involved: _Everything_ is a system-wide service with read-access to the NTFS MFT, which means it can index it in seconds (takes about ~15 seconds on my Intel Optane PCI-Ex SSD). Prior to _Everything_ there was _NTFSSearch_ and _SwiftSearch_.

Comment: @Dai - Only if windows search worked as fast and as robustly as a 3rd party app :-)

Comment: @ja72 Consider that Google can index petabytes (exbytes? yottabytes?) of data and get us relevant results within 500ms - the only reason we _expect_ local filesystem search to be relatively slower is because of laziness of Microsoft's part (disclaimer: I used to be a Blue Badge myself!). While NTFS ACLs are a primary reason why MFT-based searching isn't built-in to Windows, there's no technical reason why they couldn't build it in to the system and allow users to enable it on a discretionary basis.

Comment: You should expect this operation to take a long time -- even on relatively small systems there will be thousands of files.  Why not use the file chooser widget for this? 
If that's not feasible, is there is a way to do `GetAllFiles` ahead of time and save the results in a text file, or maybe operate on a partial list?

Comment: @Dai Alright, I'll just sic Google's warehouses of parallel servers on one spinning disk drive and time will cease to exist.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I know you’re being sarcastic, but my point is that there’s no reason for Windows’ search service for being so _aneamic_ and slovenly for local system resources. Microsoft’s problem is their search system is deliberately geared towards their ill-conceived archetype of what a typical user does (photos, “documents”, etc) that deliberately hides technical details - and that’s what ruins it. It pains me no-end that Windows doesn’t consider `*.c` files worthy of indexing - even though they’re plaintext, ARGH!

Comment: Disregarding the slowness of doing an all intensive recursive file search, what user wants to scroll through tens of thousands of files in a single ListBox?  I hope you have some kind of filtering in mind to reduce the number of files being viewed.  How about implementing a paging model so you are only presented with X number of files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

> It works but is very slow. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Yes.

1. Install voidtools' Everything: https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/
2. Configure *Everything* as a Windows Service (instead of as a per-user application)
3. Use *Everything*'s SDK ( https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/sdk/ ) to query the *Everything* Windows Service from your C# code.